# One abbreviation for various commands with different prefix?

Tags: abbreviations

To take a short cut in writing markdown files I need an abbreviation which can combine these abbreviations,

````
autocmd FileType * iabbrev pythoncode ```python```<left><left><left><cr>jjO<C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<cr>    
autocmd FileType * iabbrev vimcode ```vim```<left><left><left><cr>jjO<C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<cr>    
autocmd FileType * iabbrev bashcode ```bash```<left><left><left><cr>jjO<C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<cr>
````

into one,

````
autocmd FileType * iabbrev [aLanguage]code ```[aLanguage]```<left><left><left><cr>jjO<C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<cr>
````

I don't know how to start with. In the input the "code" can be put ahead, resulting in the command being `code[aLanguage]`, if it is more eligible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a loop and `exec`:

````
for l in ["python", "vim", "bash"]
    exec 'autocmd FileType * iabbrev' l."code ```" l."```<left><left><left><cr>jjO<C-R>=Eatchar('\s')<cr>"
endfor
````

Comment: Oh, great. It's also scalable.

Comment: @Lerner you could use a single abbreviation that uses the `filetype`. You can get it as a variable: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14717933/2072269